# Windows: How to run a shell script out of a simple CGI python server

Tags: python, shell, cgi

I have made a python Srver using http.server

```
python -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

Server is running and i am able to run a python script on it. I am trying to **run shell file** with similar content.
I think i am not bale to make the shell file executable. Lookign for soemthing like **chmod +x filename.sh** in windows.

Ubuntu Equivalent link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/229589/how-to-make-a-file-e-g-a-sh-script-executable-so-it-can-be-ran-from-terminal

Currently i am getting this error:

```
Content-type text/htmlException happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 1659)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 313, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)


File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 341, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\server.py", line 422, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\server.py", line 410, in handle_one_request
    method()

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\server.py", line 645, in do_GET
    f = self.send_head()

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\server.py", line 953, in send_head
    return self.run_cgi()

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\server.py", line 1161, in run_cgi
    env = env

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
< h1 >Hello World< /h1 >
```

**Updated**

**Content of Python file:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Content-type text/html")
print("")
print("< h1 > Hello World < / h1 >")`
```

**Output:**(on browser screen)

```
Hello World
```

**Shell File Content**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type text/html"
echo ""
echo "< h1 >Hello World< /h1 >" `
```

**Output:**
Above mentioned error.

Want the similar output **Hello World.**

Comment: You try to run HTML-Code as a program. So what do you expect despite failing?

Comment: updated the question : with what is the expected and current output.

Answer (score 0):

In windows there are no bash-scripts. You only have .bat-Files with very limited syntax. If you try to run your script as `filename.sh` windows tries to find a program associated with the extension `.sh` and fails. You should rename your file to `filename.bat`.